# When selecting an action bar tab manually, tab initially starts blank

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

In my onCreate() method I try to manually select one of my tabs to force it to pre-load, then switch back to the first tab manually. However, when I start, the first tab initally displays a blank screen and only loads after selecting another and then reselecting. This is my code in onCreate:

```
        //set up tabs
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Set Current Location")
                .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<SetCurrentLocationFragment>(currLocFragment,this,SetCurrentLocationFragment.class)),true);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Input Trip")
                .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<InputNewTripFragment>(inputNewTripFragment,this,InputNewTripFragment.class)));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("View Trip")
                .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<FoodMilesFragment>(calcMilesFragment,this,FoodMilesFragment.class)));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Past Trips")
                .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<TripHistoryFragment>(tripHistoryFragment,this,TripHistoryFragment.class)));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Trip Map")
                .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<ResultsMapFragment>(resultsMapFragment,this,ResultsMapFragment.class)));
//quickly pre-load the View Trip 
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
```

And this is my TabListener

```
    private class CustomTabListener<T extends Fragment> implements TabListener {

    private Fragment fragment;
    private final Activity mBaseActivity;//activity to attach fragment to
    private final Class<T> mFragmentClass;

    public CustomTabListener(Fragment fragment, Activity activity, Class<T> fragClass)
    {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        mBaseActivity = activity;
        mFragmentClass = fragClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(fragment == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fragment must already be instantiated.");

        }

        //if the fragment has not yet been added to the activity, add it now
        if(fragment.getActivity() == null || !fragment.isAdded())
            ft.add(R.id.tabFragmentFrame, fragment);

        ft.show(fragment);

        fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(fragment != null)
        {
            ft.remove(fragment);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Something worth mentioning as well is that this version of my TabListener, with `ft.hide(fragment)` substituted for `ft.remove(fragment)` led to IllegalStateExceptions - Fragment already added.

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(fragment == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fragment must already be instantiated.");

        }

        //if the fragment has not yet been added to the activity, add it now
        if(fragment.getActivity() == null || !fragment.isAdded())
            ft.add(R.id.tabFragmentFrame, fragment);

        ft.show(fragment);

        fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(fragment != null)
        {
            ft.hide(fragment);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing you should take care of is when you select the tab on create from code, all the events should be fired that would fire when selected the tab manually.

Answer (score 0):

While I still do not know why my code before was not working - I did find that adding the tab into the specified position with setSelected = true would indeed make it appear.

```
//set up tabs   
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Input Trip")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<InputNewTripFragment>(inputNewTripFragment,this,InputNewTripFragment.class)),0);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("View Trip Footprint")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<FoodMilesFragment>(calcFoodMilesFragment,this,FoodMilesFragment.class)),1);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Past Trips")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<TripHistoryFragment>(tripHistoryFragment,this,TripHistoryFragment.class)),2);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Trip Map")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<ResultsMapFragment>(resultsMapFragment,this,ResultsMapFragment.class)),3);

    //quickly pre-load the Food Miles Trip Footprint
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Set Current Location")
            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<SetCurrentLocationFragment>(currLocFragment,this,SetCurrentLocationFragment.class)),0,true);
```